# C++ syntax of template class with pure virtual function?

Tags: c++, templates, virtual, pure-virtual

I have only a tenuous familiarity with C++ templates, and the addition of a pure virtual function to a template class has exhausted my ability to satisfy the compiler.

The following code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class Pearl
{
    public:
        Pearl(int value);
        virtual ~Pearl();

    protected:
        int mValue;
};

Pearl::Pearl(int value)
    : mValue(value)
{
    std::cout << "$" << mValue << " Pearl created" << std::endl;
}

Pearl::~Pearl()
{
    std::cout << "$" << mValue << " Pearl destroyed" << std::endl;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class Oyster
{
    public:
        Oyster(std::string str, int value);
        virtual ~Oyster();

    protected:
        Pearl mPearl;
        std::string mName;

    friend class OStreamer;
};

Oyster::Oyster(std::string name, int value)
    : mName(name)
    , mPearl(value)
{
    std::cout << "Oyster " << mName << " created" << std::endl;
}

Oyster::~Oyster()
{
    std::cout << "Oyster " << mName << " destroyed" << std::endl;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template <typename T> class Streamer
{
    public:
        Streamer(T& rT, unsigned int flags);
        ~Streamer();

        virtual std::ostream Display() = 0;

        static const unsigned int A = 0x1;
        static const unsigned int B = 0x2;

    protected:
        T& mrT; // Aah pity the foo!
        unsigned int mFlags;

    friend class OStreamer;
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class OStreamer : public Streamer<Oyster>
{
    public:
        OStreamer(Oyster oyster, unsigned int flags);
        virtual std::ostream Display();
};

OStreamer::OStreamer(Oyster oyster, unsigned int flags)
    : Streamer<Oyster>(oyster, flags)
{
}

std::ostream OStreamer::Display()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;

    oss << "Oyster[" << mrT.mName << "]" << std::endl;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template <typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Streamer<T> streamer)
{
    return os;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    Oyster sam("Sam", 50);

    std::cout << OStreamer(sam, OStreamer::A) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

...generates the following compiler error (with g++ 4.4.7):

```
>g++ main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:107: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Streamer<Oyster>’
main.cpp:56: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Streamer<Oyster>’:
main.cpp:61: note:      std::ostream Streamer<T>::Display() [with T = Oyster]
```

Can someone help me understand why the compiler doesn't accept the implementation of OStreamer::Display() as the required override of Streamer::Display()?

As context: this is experimental, contrived code, to familiarize myself with combining template classes with pure virtual functions. What I'd like to accomplish with this code is implement an otream operator for OStreamer objects that calls OStreamer::Display. I recognize that the ostream operator might need some tweaking, but I *think* that's not the problem at play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your operator overload to:

```
template <typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,
                           const Streamer<T> &streamer)
{
    return os;
}
```

Passing a parameter of `const Streamer<t>` requires making a copy of the base class, which can't be done, of course, because it is virtual.

Passing a reference avoids this problem.

Comment: Just bet me to it. +1

Comment: D'oh! I've been staring at the code for too long and totally glossed over that. I humbly accept my public embarrassment. :) Thank you, @sam-varshavchik!